# How to segue back to filled-in version of TableViewController (Swift)?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, segue, cell

I am building a room-booking app for iOS in Xcode 9.3.
Here is the basic layout:

- First `TableViewController`(TVC1): starts empty. Pressing '+' pops up the
- Second `TableViewController`(TVC2) with many fields to fill in.

Once the 'Done' button on TVC2 is pressed I get back to TVC1 which now has a cell (Subtitle style) containing the details inserted.

I would now like to tap on said cell and get back to TVC2 to either check or modify the data.
I have created the segue but upon tapping I get the same version of TVC2 that I get when pressing '+', not the filled in one.

What am I doing wrong?

This is the code relative to TVC1 that I need to edit:

```
import UIKit

class RegistrationTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var registrations: [Registration] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return registrations.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RegistrationCell", for: indexPath)

    let registration = registrations[indexPath.row]
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .short

    cell.textLabel?.text = registration.firstName + " " + registration.lastName
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = dateFormatter.string(from: registration.checkInDate) + " - " + registration.roomType.name

    return cell
}

@IBAction func unwindFromAddRegistration(unwindSegue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    guard let addRegistrationTableViewController = unwindSegue.source as? AddRegistrationTableViewController,
        let registration = addRegistrationTableViewController.registration else { return }

    registrations.append(registration)
    tableView.reloadData()
}

// MARK: Challenge.
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ViewReservationDetails" {


    }
}
```

And here is the code for (TVC2) so that you have more or less all the app available.

```
import UIKit

class AddRegistrationTableViewController: UITableViewController, SelectRoomTypeTableViewControllerDelegate {
// MARK: Properties
let checkInDatePickerCellIndexPath = IndexPath(row: 1, section: 1)
let checkOutDatePickerCellIndexPath = IndexPath(row: 3, section: 1)

var isCheckInDatePickerShown: Bool = false {
    didSet {
        checkInDatePicker.isHidden = !isCheckInDatePickerShown
    }
}
var isCheckOutDatePickerShown: Bool = false {
    didSet {
        checkOutDatePicker.isHidden = !isCheckOutDatePickerShown
    }
}

var roomType: RoomType?
var registration: Registration? {
    guard let roomType = roomType else { return nil }

    let firstName = firstNameTextField.text ?? ""
    let lastName = lastNameTextField.text ?? ""
    let email = emailTextField.text ?? ""
    let checkInDate = checkInDatePicker.date
    let checkOutDate = checkOutDatePicker.date
    let numberOfAdults = Int(numberOfAdultsStepper.value)
    let numberOfChildren = Int(numberOfChildrenStepper.value)
    let hasWifi = wifiSwitch.isOn

    return Registration(firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, emailAddress: email, checkInDate: checkInDate, checkOutDate: checkOutDate, numberOfAdults: numberOfAdults, numberOfChildren: numberOfChildren, roomType: roomType, wifi: hasWifi)
}

var selectedItem: Registration?

// MARK: Outlets
@IBOutlet weak var firstNameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var lastNameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var checkInDateLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var checkInDatePicker: UIDatePicker!
@IBOutlet weak var checkOutDateLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var checkOutDatePicker: UIDatePicker!

@IBOutlet weak var numberOfAdultsLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var numberOfAdultsStepper: UIStepper!
@IBOutlet weak var numberOfChildrenLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var numberOfChildrenStepper: UIStepper!

@IBOutlet weak var roomTypeLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var wifiSwitch: UISwitch!

// MARK: Actions
@IBAction func datePickerValueChanged(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {
    updateDateViews()
}
@IBAction func stepperValueChanged(_ sender: UIStepper) {
    updateNumberOfGuests()
}
@IBAction func wifiSwitchChanged(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    // implemented later
}
@IBAction func cancelButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
// MARK: Methods
func updateDateViews() {
    checkOutDatePicker.minimumDate = checkInDatePicker.date.addingTimeInterval(86400)

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium

    checkInDateLabel.text = dateFormatter.string(from: checkInDatePicker.date)
    checkOutDateLabel.text = dateFormatter.string(from: checkOutDatePicker.date)
}

func updateNumberOfGuests() {
    numberOfAdultsLabel.text = "\(Int(numberOfAdultsStepper.value))"
    numberOfChildrenLabel.text = "\(Int(numberOfChildrenStepper.value))"
}

func updateRoomType() {
    if let roomType = roomType {
        roomTypeLabel.text = roomType.name
    } else {
        roomTypeLabel.text = "Not Set"
    }
}

func didSelect(roomType: RoomType) {
    self.roomType = roomType
    updateRoomType()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let midnightToday = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date())
    checkInDatePicker.minimumDate = midnightToday
    checkInDatePicker.date = midnightToday

    updateDateViews()
    updateNumberOfGuests()
    updateRoomType()
}

// MARK: TableView Data
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    switch (indexPath.section, indexPath.row) {
    case (checkInDatePickerCellIndexPath.section, checkInDatePickerCellIndexPath.row):
        if isCheckInDatePickerShown {
            return 216.0
        } else {
            return 0.0
        }
    case (checkOutDatePickerCellIndexPath.section, checkOutDatePickerCellIndexPath.row):
        if isCheckOutDatePickerShown {
            return 216.0
        } else {
            return 0.0
        }
    default:
        return 44.0
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    switch (indexPath.section, indexPath.row) {
    case (checkInDatePickerCellIndexPath.section, checkInDatePickerCellIndexPath.row - 1):
        if isCheckInDatePickerShown {
            isCheckInDatePickerShown = false
        } else if isCheckOutDatePickerShown {
            isCheckOutDatePickerShown = false
            isCheckInDatePickerShown = true
        } else {
            isCheckInDatePickerShown = true
        }

        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.endUpdates()

    case (checkOutDatePickerCellIndexPath.section, checkOutDatePickerCellIndexPath.row - 1):
        if isCheckOutDatePickerShown {
            isCheckOutDatePickerShown = false
        } else if isCheckInDatePickerShown {
            isCheckInDatePickerShown = false
            isCheckOutDatePickerShown = true
        } else {
            isCheckOutDatePickerShown = true
        }

        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.endUpdates()

    default:
        break
    }
}

// MARK: Navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "SelectRoomType" {
        let destinationViewController = segue.destination as? SelectRoomTypeTableViewController
        destinationViewController?.delegate = self
        destinationViewController?.roomType = roomType
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
```

}

The challenge to this tutorial says to start from here and: 
"Update the `RegistrationTableViewController`(TVC1) with a segue that allows the user to select and view the details of a registration in the `AddRegistrationTableViewController`(TVC2).

Hope this helps to provide the right solution.

Comment: can you please share your tried code?

Comment: Added. At the end you can see my prepare(for segue) method but everything I tried to add inside didn't change the result. Do you need also the code relative to the other TVC?

Comment: Now I have added the full code of the app (separate structs excluded, but they should be clear from what is already there).

Answer (score 0):

Create a property let say `selectedItem` in TVC2 screen.

```
var selectedItem: Registration?
```

Modify prepare for cell ...

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

   if segue.identifier == "ViewReservationDetails" {

         let sourceCell = sender as! UITableViewCell

         if let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: sourceCell) {

            if let dest = segue.destination as? <#Destination view controller#> {

              dest.selectedItem = registrations[indexPath.row]
            }
         }
    }
 }
```

And finally in your destination view controller (having TVC2) you need to check `selectedItem` and assign value in `viewDidLoad:` or wherever.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let  item = selectedItem {
        //here set value as you want to views

     }
}
```

Comment: A 'Registration?' property in TVC2 is already there so I could actually use that one but when I do it says that it is a 'get-only property'.  If I declare a new one it says that the class is missing initialisers. Would a { get set } solve it?

Comment: When you create a new property make it `optional` like `let newProperty: Registration?`. The `?` sign denotes that it is an optional property.

Comment: I did exactly as you said but the compiler says it is a 'get-only property'. I am adding the code of the Registration property above.

Comment: Yes, its a get only property.

Comment: If I use the already present property the compiler says that it is a 'get-only property', if I use yours, even with the '?' it says that the class is missing initialisers.

Comment: No, compiler will not complain if you declared a property with `?`... Declare like `let regis: Registration?`. It won't ask for initialiser.

Comment: What should I write instead of // here set value as you want to views?

Comment: Here you need to fill data to respected views. for eg. you have first name the `txtFirstName.text = registration.firstName`, same way fill all the data.

Comment: I started to implement your solution but had to flee for the office, it seems to work, though... will check tonight and mark the post and the answers accordingly. Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear that !!:)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171186/discussion-between-neera-the-wild-mage-and-mahendra-gp).

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)`:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "ViewReservationDetails", sender: indexPath)
}
```

Then, in TVC1’s `prepare(for:sender:)` you pass the selected `registrations` element plus a completion handler to TVC2, like this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ViewReservationDetails" {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? AddRegistrationTableViewController, let indexPath = sender as? IndexPath {
            destination.registration = registrations[indexPath.row]
            destination.completionHandler = { (registration) in
                self.registrations.append(registration)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In TVC2, you declare a property `completionHandler` like this:

```
var completionHandler: ((Registration) -> Void)?
```

and you call this handler in `viewWillDisappear`:

```
completionHandler?(newRegistration)
```

with `newRegistration` being the newly created element to be added to the Registration array. This way, you won’t need an unwind segue.

Comment: Your suggested solution gives a few errors.  1) it tells me that `destination`cannot be a constant because it is a computed property. Did you want to say 'if let destination ...' ?

Comment: In any case, even with that I get returned to an empty TVC2, not the desired one.

Comment: What do you mean when you say you’ll be returned to TVC2? You should return from TVC2 to TVC1…?

Comment: Sorry I’m at work now. I need to select row in TVC1 and be brought back to the TVC2 in the state it was when it was being edited.

Comment: Any solution proposed does not seem to work. I'm sorry but I get an empty TVC2 every time I select it while I would like to populate it with the data just saved in the `registrations` array.

Comment: Hey @NeeratheWildMage, please give it another try. I have just added some more details to my previous answer—it now includes the code required for passing the selected item over to the edit controller. Hope you get it done now. You might want to add a print statement in TVC2’s `viewDidLoad` method displaying the contents of `registration` just to be sure the data is being passed correctly.

Comment: Thank you, Tom but ... no luck ... this seems to be trickier than it looks like at first glance. First problem: your line `destination.registration = registrations[indexPath.row]` triggers the following error: "Cannot assign to property: registration is a get-only property". We tried (in the other answer) to create a new `Registration` property but it didn't help. My nose says that the app saves data to the array when the done button is pressed the first time and TVC2 transitions to TVC1 but then, when I want to go back, the array is not called anymore and an empty TVC2 is summoned.

Comment: The error comes from the fact that `registration` is a computed property in your case. Please try to change it to a regular property, i. e., remove the curly brackets after `var registration: Registration?` and move the code contained therein to  `viewWillDisappear`.

Comment: I would prefer not to change the base code of the app if possible and just add what would make me load the proper data in the TVC. Any idea?

Comment: Well, my ideas are in the answer above. It works—I'm using it throughout my apps. When using computed properties you are tightly coupling data storage with actions—which in your case seems too tight as this is one of the causes of your problem. If you switch to loose coupling you gain the flexibility required to get your code running. Also, the necessary changes involve only a handful of lines of code.

Comment: Good, I will try making a copy of the project. But tell me, when you use it in your projects, is the data successfully loaded back when you select the cell?

Comment: Also, what exactly should I type instead of (newRegistration) in completionHandler?(...)

Comment: Unfortunately, adding all your suggested changes the app starts crashing. I think I will either need personal help where someone may look at my project directly (i.e.: give me an email address where to send this to) or I will just let it as is and when I will be more proficient come back and finish it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171241/discussion-between-tom-e-and-neera-the-wild-mage).